# How to work with huge matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm working with huge dense matrices in R (Matrix package, Matrix data type) where one of my matrix exceeds the theoretical limit of an R matrix (it is supposed to be 58932 by 58932)

I need to conduct basic matrix operations such as add and multiply.

My question is: Is there a package in R or some other software which I can use to store these huge matrices as well as work with them.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: The problem is as described: I need to work with dense matrices that exceeds the limit of 2^51 value of a matrix.

Tasks: adding, multiplication, and computing the inverse of the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Try the class `big.matrix` in the CRAN [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf) `bigmemory`.

http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/temp/bigmemory-vignette.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I mainly use Windows, so `bigmemory` does not work for me.
I wrote my own package `filematrix` doing about the same with pure R code.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/filematrix/index.html

I tested it on matrices over 1 TB in size.
Your 60,000 x 60,000 matrix should take only 28 GB as a file.

Happy to answer any questions about it.

Comment: Note that bigmemory now also works on Windows in the latest CRAN version!